# scrapy_splash.SplashRequest doesn't execute callback function when scheduled by scrapyd

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd, scrapy-splash

I did encounter some strange behaviour (to my perspective of knowledge) of SplashRequest's callback when it's executed by scrapyd.

#### Scrapy Sourcecode

```
from scrapy.spiders.Spider import Spider
from scrapy import Request
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
class SiteSaveSpider(Spider):

    def __init__(self, domain='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(SiteSaveSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = [domain]
        self.allowed_domains = [domain]
    name = "sitesavespider"


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse, args={'wait':0.5})

            print "TEST after yield"

    def parse(self, response):
        print "TEST in parse"
        with open('/some_path/test.html', 'w') as f:
            for line in response.body:
                f.write(line)
```

#### Log for internal Scrapy Crawler

The callback parse function is executed when started by

```
scrapy crawl sitesavespider -a domain="https://www.facebook.com"
...
2017-01-29 14:12:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-29 14:12:37 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
TEST after yield
2017-01-29 14:12:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.facebook.com via http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
TEST in parse
2017-01-29 14:12:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
...
```

#### Log for scrapyd

When starting the same spider by using scrapyd it will return directly after the SplashRequest:

```
>>>scrapyd.schedule("feedbot","sitesavespider",domain="https://www.facebook.com")
u'f2f4e090e62d11e69da1342387f8a0c9'

cat f2f4e090e62d11e69da1342387f8a0c9.log
... 
2017-01-29 14:19:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-01-29 14:19:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-01-29 14:19:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.facebook.com via http://127.0.0.1:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2017-01-29 14:19:58 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
...
```

Is somebody aware of this problem or could help me to find my mistakes?

Comment: I can see you've configured SPLASH_URL as `http://127.0.0.1:8050` - can you confirm Splash is available at this location for scrapyd? Is scrapyd running on the same machine?

Comment: Yeah, scrapyd is running on `127.0.0.0:6800`. As it gives back `200` as http-code I assume successful connection with splash?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to reconstruct the problem on another computer, it wasn't there anymore and I cannot proof it. For others, trying to debug such issues:

- print calls in own spider won't be outputted by scrapyd into the logfile by default, but into the terminalsession where scrapyd was started

```
2017-02-21 16:24:29+0100 [HTTPChannel,0,127.0.0.1] 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2017:15:24:28 +0000] "GET /listjobs.json?project=feedbot HTTP/1.1" 200 199 "-" "python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-86-generic"
2017-02-21 16:24:29+0100 [Launcher,17915/stdout] TEST after yield
TEST in parse
2017-02-21 16:24:29+0100 [HTTPChannel,0,127.0.0.1] 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2017:15:24:28 +0000] "GET /listjobs.json?project=feedbot HTTP/1.1" 200 199 "-" "python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-86-generic"
```